# Embedding a pie chart in ASP.NET (Razor syntax)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, charts

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET (have been coding in WPF a long time, but new to ASP) and I'm trying to create a dashboard application that shows four pie charts. I've followed the instructions on [this](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) link, but I either get a chart on the entire page, or a broken image (as if the `<img>` source is not valid)

Can someone please explain to me how to achieve this behavior? I just want to display a simple pie chart on my page, that's it.

Thanks! (and sorry if this is a duplicated post, I've found other similar questions but none using the Razor syntax)

**EDIT - Here's my code:**

Index.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Chart Example</h1>
    <p>
        The following chart is generated by the <em>ChartView.cshtml</em> file, but is shown
        in this page.
    </p>
    <p><img src="ChartView.cshtml" /> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My ChartView.cshtml: (located in the same folder as Index.cshtml)

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(600, 400)
       .AddTitle("Employees")
       .AddSeries(chartType: "column",
          xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
          yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" });

    if (myChart != null)
    {
        myChart.Write();
    }
}
```

This is what I get on the browser:
[image]

Comment: Show the code you have tried.

Comment: You need to post code for us to be able to diagnose

Comment: Thanks, I've added my code

Comment: Love the part in the tutorial that say simply, "Run the page in the browser. The browser displays the chart." no explanation of *what* page...  make sure you get the image working first before adding it to an `img src=` so you can see any YSOD (yellow screen of death) messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return a `.cshtml` file (unless you fiddle dangerously with various internal settings - not recommended).

You should be pointing to an `action`.

The easiest way to test this is by opening the `src` directly in the browser - in this case "ChartView.cshtml" and you *should* get a 404.

You'll need to add an action to your controller that returns the view.

```
public HomeController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult ChartView() 
    { 
        return View();
    }
```

then

```
<img src='@Url.Action("ChartView", "Home")' alt="Chart"/>
```

You can test this by opening in the browser:

```
/Home/ChartView
```

(this assumes that ChartView.cshtml is in the folder "Views/Home")

---

As you're new to MVC, quick explanation.  There a 'routeConfig.cs' which routes incoming urls to an action(method) on a controller(class).  The controller loads the view (cshtml) and applies all the server-side code then returns the rendered html to the user.

You do not navigate directly to cshtml pages but navigate instead to actions via the url.

The default route config gives you urls such as:

```
http://[site]/[controller]/[action]
```

Note that [controller] does not include "Controller", so "HomeController" becomes "/Home/"

Also, by convention, if you don't specify a view name in 'View()' then it will look in your solution folder "/Views/[controller]/[action].cshml' (among other locations such as '/Views/Shared/[action].cshtml' (also configurable, but these are the defaults).

Answer (score 1):

you easely can combine 
http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/index.html
in mvc (razor syntax)

or you can use chart helper

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart

change to:

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(600, 400)
       .AddTitle("Employees")
       .AddSeries("SomeName",chartType: "Pie",
          xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
          yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" });

    if (myChart != null)
    {
        myChart.Write();
    }
}
```

you have to lunch it in iis or some development server

Comment: Thanks Shlomi, this change still shows a broken image (see my updated question for the result that I'm getting)

Comment: try now i added "SomeName"

Comment: thanks, do you lunch it from Visual Studio ? or just view in browser ? try to lunch it with debug. or try open it in http://localhost:XXXX/ChartView.cshtml